# Не получается сделать из цикла с предусловием цикл с постусловием. C#

Tags: c#

При введении через консоль 0, цикл идти не должен.

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            while (x!=0)
            {
                if (x % 2 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine("Четное");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Нечетное");
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так должно быть:

```csharp
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Введите число");
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    if (x != 0)
        Console.WriteLine(x % 2 == 0 ? "Четное" : "Нечетное");
} while(x != 0);
```

Но вообще пример есть даже в документации. Надо читать [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do)

Comment: нужно с do и while:)

Comment: @Maria а, я уж и забыл, что в C# есть do while )

Comment: Вот такой код у меня тоже был, но проблема в том, что при введении числа 0 - выводится, что число четное, а такого быть не должно(

Comment: @Maria Не знаю, насколько это подходит, но можно вот так `if (x != 0) Console.WriteLine(x % 2 == 0 ? "Четное" : "Нечетное")`

Comment: @aepot Спасибо))

Comment: @Maria ответ отредактирован, и если все хорошо, то уже можно его одобрить.

Comment: Вообще, если бы я писал такой код для проекта, я бы вышел при нуле по break, чтобы не делать две одинаковых проверки. Поэтому в реальной жизни никто do while и не пользуется, а пишут while(true) и выходят из цикла по условию через break где это удобнее по коду. Я поэтому про do while и забыл, что он есть вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf с `do {} while(true)` и условным `break` действительно было бы логичнее, но тогда смысла от цикла с пост-условием не будет, и можно использовать с предусловием точно так же. Здесь оно хотя-бы аффектит логику. В этом коде есть другая проблема. Если пользователь введет не число, будет исключение, но я не стал этому уделять внимание. :)

Comment: @aepot Ну понятно, что тут учебное задание, поэтому так всё. Я просто говорю, что в реальной жизни do while практически не нужен. В тот же Python поэтому его вообще не завезли, насколько я помню %)

Comment: @CrazyElf полностью с вами согласна, но да, это учебное заведение(